# Reducing the time spent on Loading by using DB query to retrieve data instead of Eloquent Query (where in or Join)

Tags: laravel

My web app is taking a long time to load mostly retrieving data from the database to the resource view, which I think may come as a result of me using eloquent query to retrieve, So I would like a DB query version of it. Please Help with this problem

```html
 <tbody>
        <?php
        $i = 0
        ?>
        @foreach ($fields as $field)
        <?php
        $i++
        ?>
        <tr>
         <td>{{$i}}</td>
         <td>{{$field->fieldname}}</td>
         <td>{{$field->farmer_name}}</td>
         <td>{{$field->farmer_idno}}</td>
         <td>{{$field->crop}}</td>
         <td>{{$field->farmblocksno}}</td>
         <td>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">

            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Options
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                <a href="{{ route('admins.farmdetails',$field->id) }}" class="dropdown-item">View Details</a>
                <a href="{{ route('fields.edit', $field->id) }}" class="dropdown-item">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="show_crop({{$field->id}})" class="dropdown-item">Collect</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="show_field({{$field->id}})" class="dropdown-item">Offer Service</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

```php
  FarmerController.php

          public function farmers(){
        
            $farmers = Farmer::with('fields')->latest()->get();
            $fields = Field::with('farmers')->latest()->get();
            $offers = Offer::latest()->get();
            $soil = Order::where('sname', 'Soil Testing')->where('status', 0)->count();
            $collection = Order::where('sname', 'Produce Collection')->where('status', 0)->count();
            $registration = Order::where('sname', 'Farmer Registration')->where('status', 0)->count();
            $nyota = Order::where('sname', 'Nyota Beans')->where('status', 0)->count();
            $shears = Order::where('sname', 'Pruning Shears')->where('status', 0)->count();
            $secateurs = Order::where('sname', 'Avocado Harvesting Secateurs')->count();
            $traps = Order::where('sname', 'FCM Traps & Housing')->where('status', 0)->count();
            $flytraps = Order::where('sname', 'Fruit Fly Traps and Housing')->where('status', 0)->count();
            $post = DB::table('crop')->get('*')->toArray();
            foreach($post as $row)
            {
              $data[] = array
              (
                'label'=>$row->crop,
                'y'=>$row->expectedvolume
              ); 
            }
  // return view('statics',['data' => $data]);
            return view('admins.farmers', ['data' => $data, 'collection' => $collection, 'registration' => $registration, 'farmers' => $farmers, 'fields' => $fields,'soil' => $soil, 'nyota' => $nyota, 'shears' => $shears, 'secateurs' => $secateurs, 'traps' => $traps, 'flytraps' => $flytraps, 'offers'=>$offers,]);
          }
```

Web.php

```
      Route::get('farmers', [FarmerController::class, 'farmers'])->name('farmers');
```

Comment: I don't think eloquent is the problem here. You should build your function in a better way because you are calling you DB multiple time where tou can make less call. For example, all your count(), you can get that info in one request to the DB like this: Order::where('status', 0)->groupBy('sname')->selectRaw('COUNT(id) as count')->get()

Answer (score 0):

U can test it with DB facade if u think it affects your performance, but Eloquent ORM is in fact slower noticable ONLY on larger data sets. How many rows do u have in this queries? Because of using all where statements i dont think u have too much results and therefore i dont think eloquent is a issue here.
Simply care for N+1 problems, do less queries in eloquent where possible, for example probably some of this data has relationships so u can load it all with just 1 query instead of query for each model separately. Also u can use eager load.